# Do I need wp-tinymce-js?

Tags: block-editor

WordPress block editor is very slow. Gutenberg is loading a lot of javascript files. In my case 83 .js files. One of the largest sized file is `wp-tinymce-js`.

I want to dequeue it. Do I still need it if I don't use classic editor?

> Besides, can any other script or css can be dequeued without breaking
> block editor?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still required for any of the classic blocks. Even if you don't plan on writing any or using any classic blocks, it seems that that JS is still required because blocks (in the editor) aren't loaded asynchronously yet.  Asynchronously loading blocks in the editor has been requested at https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/2768 and https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/21738